# Why can't I create this table?

Tags: mysql, create-table

Creating tables in MySQL confuses me. Sometimes I'm able to get it just fine, other times it seems to yell at me for things I've done before successfully. I'm attempting to create this table with 3 columns. When I try to save the column, it tells me to please enter a valid length. I've used these lengths on these column types before, so why is it yelling at me now? I'm using a form on MySQL, so I don't know the actual SQL syntax for this, but the following is what I'm trying to do.

```
Create Table: Families
(
`Id` Int(11) Auto_Incriment Primary Key,
`Family` CHAR (255) Unique,
`Species` CHAR (255),
);
```

Why is it telling me to enter a valid length?

Comment: `Create Table: Families` shouldn't have a colon, `Species CHAR (255),` shouldn't have the extra comma.

Comment: Good thing [someone wrote all about the syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) ..

Comment: try refresh your phpmyadmin page. it help me

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `:` after `table` and the `,` before the last `)` and you misspelled `auto_increment`

```
Create Table Families
(
  `Id` Int(11) auto_increment Primary Key,
  `Family` CHAR (255) Unique,
  `Species` CHAR (255)
);
```

You could "debug" such things on your own if you use a SQL tool that highlights such erros like *MySQL Workbench*.

Comment: -I entered this syntax into the SQL field of MyPHPadmin, and it created the table just fine. But why is it that when I tried to create the table using the given form using these same values, it said to enter a "Valid Length"? What changed?

Answer (score 1):

Modify It as follow:

```
Create Table Families
(
`Id` Int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT Primary Key,
`Family` CHAR (255) Unique,
`Species` CHAR (255)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a sql query that looks something like this, also make sure you spell attributes correctly:

```
Create Table: Families
(
`Id` Int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT Primary Key,
`Family` CHAR (255) Unique,
`Species` CHAR (255),
);
```

In the future please use the mysql guide in this link:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/

Comment: You left two more mistakes in... `:-)`